# Why is it incorrect to call viewDidAppear() in ViewController (Swift)?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, mapkit

I'm currently trying to develop a gps trail recording app, and I've run into some issues while trying to reload the ViewController. Essentially, while recording a path, an MKOverlayRenderer draws the line real-time. Once the user is done recording, they can choose to upload the path (right now it's just being locally stored to an array). Each path is an object containing an array of CLLocations and conforms to MKOverlay. Currently, I have it such that viewDidAppear is called when the array is updated, with a ForEach loop to render all the paths. Without that call, the map does not update the viewcontroller with all the paths in the array.

Can someone explain why calling viewDidAppear() is wrong/bad or how I would redesign my program without using it? I've seen that it can cause "unintended actions", but I personally have not had any issues with it yet. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How about just writing a new method that does whatever you need to do and call that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#1652793) says:

> **Handle view-related notifications**
>
> When the visibility of its views changes, a view controller
> automatically calls its own methods so that subclasses can respond to
> the change. [...]
>
> The following image shows the possible visible states for a view
> controller’s views and the state transitions that can occur. [...]
>
> [image]

`viewDidAppear` indicates a *change in state*. It indicates that the view is no longer "Appearing", and is now "Appeared". Are you in charge of when this state changes? No, so you should not call `viewDidAppear` yourself. Even if you are, you certainly cannot call this when the view is already in the "Appeared" state.

See also the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear) for `viewDidAppear`:

> Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view
> hierarchy.
>
> You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated
> with presenting the view. If you override this method, you must call
> `super` at some point in your implementation.

Are you notifying your VC that "its view was added to a view hierarchy"? No, so don't call it yourself.

If you don't follow the rules and do whatever you want, then why should anything else follow the rules for your sake? Whatever code (e.g. the superclass' `viewDidAppear` implementation) that depends on `viewDidAppear` being called in the "Appearing" state would break, and probably not do what you want.

You say you "personally have not had any issues with it yet." Exactly, "yet" is the key word here. You might have been lucky that no important code depends on `viewDidAppear` being called in the intended way. What if the superclass' `viewDidAppear` does something that should only be done once per appearance of the view? By calling `viewDidAppear` yourself, you've just made it do that thing *twice*. Depending on what that thing is, it could cause no consequences at all, or completely break everything.

That could be the "unintended actions" you heard.

In any case, if you want to refresh something, make a method for it:

```
func refreshPaths() {
    // put whatever you want to do in here
}
```

Call that method in `viewDidAppear`, and also wherever else you need to.

Answer (score 0):

As Sweeper says in their excellent answer, you should NOT call viewDidAppear. That is a method the system calls. UIKit is designed so that viewDidAppear is only called once when a view is revealed. Calling it yourself will break that contract.

You should probably use you view's  `setNeedsDisplay()` method to notify your view(s) that they need to be updated.

If you're using a system view like an MKMapView, the view will redraw itself. If you're using a custom view, you'll need to implement code to handle redrawing.